# AngularJS - angularJS material slider based on string instead of integers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider

I am doing a small project to get to know AngularJS. Currently I am looking into whtat you can do with AngularJS Material.

At this moment I am messing around with the Slider functionality. See here for info: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider.

I can get this to work without problem when I use integers. Now I am trying to get this to work with strings instead of integers.

For example, I have an array with strings. The first entry would represent the number 1, entry 2 would represent the number 2 and so forth. The slider would use the strings instead of regular numbers to slide with.

Is this possible? And if so, how? I am breaking my head on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the model value of slider and subtract `1` to index your value from string array

```
<md-slider ng-model="myCtrl.counter">

{{ myCtrl.stringArray[ myCtrl.counter -1 ] }}
```